# MySQL CASE statement with tuple

Tags: mysql, sql, tuples, case, where-clause

I have this query:

```
UPDATE products_variants_relation SET
    state = CASE (products_id, variants_id)
        WHEN (3, 1) THEN (0)
        WHEN (3, 2) THEN (4)
        WHEN (3, 3) THEN (3)
        WHEN (3, 4) THEN (0)
    END
WHERE (products_id, variants_id) IN ((3, 1),(3, 2),(3, 3),(3, 4))
```

As you can probably see, I'm trying to do multiple update, because of performance. Idea is that I find the rows via combination `(products_id, variants_id)` and update another field `state` with correct value. I tried to remove parentheses around values behind `THEN`, but then I got syntax error.

This trick for multiple update works great if there are no tuples (pairs). In this particular case, MySQL throws an error:

```
#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

How should I change the query so I can do multiple updates with pairs? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Thanks to @gordon-linoff I solved it. Actually, this is also correct:

```
UPDATE products_variants_relation
    SET state = (CASE
        WHEN products_id = 3 and variants_id = 1 THEN 0
        WHEN products_id = 3 and variants_id = 2 THEN 4
        WHEN products_id = 3 and variants_id = 3 THEN 3
        WHEN products_id = 3 and variants_id = 4 THEN 0
    END)
WHERE (products_id, variants_id) IN ((3, 1),(3, 2),(3, 3),(3, 4))
```

So, tuples in where clause are allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `and` and `or`:

```
UPDATE products_variants_relation
    SET state = (CASE WHEN products_id = 3 and variants_id = 1) THEN 0
                      WHEN products_id = 3 and variants_id = 2) THEN 4
                      WHEN products_id = 3 and variants_id = 3) THEN 3
                      WHEN products_id = 3 and variants_id = 4) THEN 0
                 END)
   WHERE (products_id = 3 and variants_id = 1) OR
         (products_id = 3 and variants_id = 2) OR
         (products_id = 3 and variants_id = 3) OR
         (products_id = 3 and variants_id = 4);
```

Neither `in` nor `case` accept tuples in MySQL (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)).

You might find this easier to do using a `join`:

```
UPDATE products_variants_relation pvf
       (select 3 as pid, 1 as vid, 0 as val union all
        select 3, 2, 4 union all
        select 3, 3, 3 union all
        select 3, 4, 0
       ) newvals
       ON pvf.products_id = newvals.pid and pvf.variants_id = newvals.vid
    SET pvf.state = newvals.val;
```

The `join` does the filtering and matches the values.

Comment: Your first solution is ok for me, but I'm waiting, maybe someone has idea about tuples in case statement